# Converting analog audio to digital

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit, conversion

I'm doing an amateur conversion, on the cheap, of some old cassette tapes to digital (bootlegs and other stuff that can't be found online...)
As their quality is not great to begin with, would like to avoid using lossy mp3 format.
I have a Diamond MM VC 500 Video Capture, if anyone's familiar, which I'd used to convert VHS to digital, and it only records in these formats: 
DVD, SVCD, VCD, AVI, WMV, WMA, MPG4, & MP3.
May I record the audio in one of the lossless video and audio formats (MPG4, AVI??), then extract the audio only?
If so, would appreciate feedback as to best format to use, and any tips for success.  Thanks!

Comment: Use a 3,5 mm jack-to-jack or a cinch-to-jack cable to connect the cassette player to your PC LINE IN port, then use an audio recording program like Audacity to record the sound. You can then export it in whatever format you want.

Comment: thanks redbeam. don't believe my old HP Pavilion has a sound card (https://www.cnet.com/products/hp-pavilion-dv71245dx/specs/). and don't think inputting into headphones jack would work? any other way?

Comment: https://www.cnet.com/products/hp-pavilion-dv7-1245dx/review/  It clearly states Audio  Stereo speakers, headphone (x2)/**microphone jacks**

Comment: "don't think inputting into headphones jack would work? ", Yes it will just be careful not to overdrive the mic input with too much volume from the cassette player. I have done this with 8 track, cassette, reel to reel and Vinyl records.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Diamond](http://www.diamondmm.com/diamond-vc500-one-touch-video-capture-edit-stream.html) hardware, but not the software. It has line-level inputs already so you don't have to mess with mini-jacks & headphone sockets.

Get [Audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org) (freeware) & you can record in any audio format you like.